# Whats the right way to get numbered equation in markdown?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, pandoc

I am really confused by should I surround `$$` with my equation?

I tested 3 major used tools, vs code, jupyter and pandoc

#### With `$$`:

vscode markdown works:

[image]

jupyter notebook works:

[image]

pandoc fails:

```
Error producing PDF.
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.384 \end{align}
```

#### Without `$$`

vscode markdown fails

[image]

jupyter notebook works(without correct code highlight)

pandoc works.

---

So, which is the right way to use latex equation in markdown?

PS: Why I need both tree of them works? I write it in jupyter, use `nbconvert` it to markdown and then use `pandoc` to pdf.

Comment: I think if you use `$$`, you shouldn't need to write `begin/end{equation/aligned}`, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math But please post a minimal reproducible example of input and exact pandoc command if you need more help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VS Code.

AFAIK, [Jupyter Lab](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io) uses https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js to convert Markdown into HTML.

[nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) uses Pandoc to convert Markdown into HTML.

> So, which is the right way to use latex equation in markdown?

There is no right way to use LaTeX equation in Markdown because it will depend of your software stack as different Markdown parsers handle LaTeX equation different.